# How do you trace all connected nonzero elements in a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, depth-first-search

Suppose I define the following simple matrix in MATLAB:

```
myImage3 = zeros(10,10);
for i=1:10
    for j=i:2:10
        myImage3(i,j) = 20;
    end
end
```

Then myImage is a 10x10 matrix that looks like:

myImage3 =

```
20     0    20     0    20     0    20     0    20     0
 0    20     0    20     0    20     0    20     0    20
 0     0    20     0    20     0    20     0    20     0
 0     0     0    20     0    20     0    20     0    20
 0     0     0     0    20     0    20     0    20     0
 0     0     0     0     0    20     0    20     0    20
 0     0     0     0     0     0    20     0    20     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20     0    20
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20
```

How do I write a function that tracks or traces through all connected nonzero elements of the matrix? For example, if I start at (1,1), we have the following trace:

(1,1) --> (2,2) --> (3,3) ---> ... --> (10,10).

But if I start at (1,3), we have the following trace:

(1,3) --> (2,4) -> (3,5) ---> ... --> (8,10).

Similarly, if I start at (1,5), we have the following trace:

(1,5) --> (2,6) --> (3,7) ---> ... --> (6,10).

The elements do not need to be "20", but rather could be any non-zero number.  Also, the elements do not have to be perfectly diagonal.  They could be a zig zag like shown below:

myImage2 =

```
10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0    20     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0    21     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0    14    15    20     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0    20     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0    20     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    20
```

But notice that if I start at (1,1) again, every neighboring pixel has another non-zero neighboring pixel (i.e. connected).

The trace, starting at (1,1) would now look like:

(1,1)--> (2,2)--> (3,3) --> (4,3) --> (5,3)--> (5,4)--> (5,5)--> (6,6)--> (7,7)--> (8,8)--> (9,9)--> (10,10)

I think I need to use [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), but all the algorithms I see apply to adjacency matrices, not the type of matrices shown above.

Comment: The only reason that DFS uses an adjacency matrix is to identify which nodes are connected to the current node. Your grid provides you with that information.

Comment: @beaker - are you suggesting I should convert it to an adjacency matrix and then use dfs?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm suggesting that you should use DFS with the data structure that you have.

Comment: If you consider diagonal elements to be adjacent, the first example has a single connected component. Can you clarify? Also, can't you just use [`bwconncomp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) and then iterate over each component?